# BOOTSTRAP trigger tooltip on input element only if input val length < n

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I would like to show tooltip when `input.val().length <= 3` then hide tooltip when > 3 chars

Check this out:

```
<input type="text" id="nav-search"/>


$('#nav-search').on('keyup',function(){
   var _keys = $(this).val();
   if(_keys.length <= 3){
   $(this).tooltip({'trigger':'focus',position:'right'});
   $(this).trigger('focusin');

   }
  });
```

it doesn't works obviously :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Theoretically, it should work:

```
$("#nav-search").on("keyup", function() {
    if (this.value.length <= 3) {
        $(this).tooltip("show");
    } else {
        $(this).tooltip("hide");
    }
}).tooltip({
    placement: "right",
    trigger: "focus"
});​
```

Practically, it works.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FvxnN/

Comment: how can i make it visible when focusin and length <= 3? then how to hide that on keyup when length > 3 ? thanks man your's gonna be the answer!!

Comment: cause now with only keyup event the tooltip is "flashing" until they are 4 chars, i would like no flashing (hide /show + hide/show + hide/show)

Comment: Both fiddles stopped working because Bootstrap moved their files. I updated the references in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FvxnN/102/). Thanks for the simple example!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#nav-search').bind('keyup',function(){
   var _keys = $(this).val();
   if(_keys.length <= 3){
   $(this).tooltip({'trigger':'focus',position:'right'});
   $(this).trigger('focusin');

   }else{

  //perform some action
  }
  });
```